# Maya "invalid object type"

Tags: python, maya

I am having an error of (Invalid object name: [u'locator1']) when I run my code as show below:

```
loc = cmds.spaceLocator()
selectedJoints = cmds.ls(sl=True)
childJoint = cmds.listRelatives( selectedJoints[0], children = 1 )
cmds.aimConstraint(childJoint, selectedJoints[0], aim = (1,0,0), u=(0,1,0), worldUpObject = loc, worldUpType= 'object')
```

The error seems to show up when I run the last code which is

```
cmds.aimConstraint(childJoint, selectedJoints[0], aim = (1,0,0), u=(0,1,0), worldUpObject = loc, worldUpType= 'object')
```

I know, somehow I need to capture the object in order to work, but I quite don't know how to, I am new to python. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

```
childJoint = cmds.listRelatives( selectedJoints[0], children = 1 )
```

Will return  a list and you need to pass the index like this

```
if childJoint:
    cmds.aimConstraint(childJoint[0], selectedJoints[0], aim = (1,0,0), u=(0,1,0), worldUpObject = loc, worldUpType= 'object')
```

Comment: To reinforce what Achayan is saying `Invalid object name` is almost always you passing a list or tuple (or sometimes a 'None`) to a function that expects one string name